# Qt C++ layout выходит за пределы TabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, layout

Хочу добиться корректного расположения `QToolBox` в `QTabWidget`. Суть такая: есть 6 вкладок в `tabWidget`, в каждой из них создаётся по 2 вкладки `toolBox`. Всё создаётся, но `layout` выходит за пределы `tabWidget`. Если проделывать такое с `QPushButton`, то проблемы нет. Сама главная форма находится в дизайнере и в ней же `verticalLayout`, в который в итоге вставляю `tabWidget`. Если тоже самое делать в дизайнере, то всё нормально. Минимальный пример прикрепил:

```
QStringList variantList;
variantList << "1,0" << "0,9" << "0,8" << "0,7" << "0,6" << "0,5";
QStringList subZones;
subZones << "One" << "Two";

tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
for (int i = 0; i < variantList.count(); i++)
{
    QWidget * newTab = new QWidget;
    tabWidget->addTab(newTab,variantList.at(i));

    QToolBox * toolBox = new QToolBox;
    for (int i = 0; i < subZones.count(); i++)
    {
        QWidget * newTool = new QWidget;
        toolBox->addItem(newTool, subZones.at(i));
    }
    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;
    vbox->addWidget(toolBox);
    tabWidget->setLayout(vbox);
}
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(tabWidget);
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, проблема кроется в установке менеджера размещения непосредственно в `QTabWidget`. Нужно иначе. Сперва можно создать виджет-вкладку, затем добавить к нему экземпляр `QLayout`, и лишь затем перенести в `QTabWidget`.

```
QStringList variantList;
variantList << "1,0" << "0,9" << "0,8" << "0,7" << "0,6" << "0,5";
QStringList subZones;
subZones << "One" << "Two";

tabWidget = new QTabWidget;
for (int i = 0; i < variantList.count(); i++)
{  
    QToolBox *toolBox = new QToolBox;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < subZones.count(); ii++)
    {
        QWidget *newTool = new QWidget;
        toolBox->addItem(newTool, subZones.at(ii));
    }

    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;
    vbox->addWidget(toolBox);

    QWidget *newTab = new QWidget;
    newTab->setLayout(vbox);

    tabWidget->addTab(newTab,variantList.at(i));
}
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(tabWidget);
```